# Comptuting the maximum number of wins of RPS games

Tags: java, algorithm

I need help writing some code that computes the maximum possible of wins in N games of rock paper scissors.

I am given the number N, which is the number of rock paper scissor games, followed by N sets of integers (1, 2, 3), each of which link to rock, paper or scissors. However, we do not know which number links to each option. I need help computing the maximum number of games that the first person could have won.

Comment: You have only **6** possibilities to assign a number to game choice (rock, paper, scissors). Why not brute force?

Comment: would it be efficient to have six different methods for these possibilities, and then a compare statement in the main? I might take this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's consider possible cases of how the values can be ordered. We can construct a ring where each number loses to the next value.

- 1 looses aginst 2: 2 can't loose against 1, so it can only loose against 3 and 3 must loose against 1 so `1 < 2 < 3 < 1`, where `a < b` indicates "a looses against b"
- 2 looses against 1: 1 can't loose against 2, so it must loose against 3 and must loose against 2 so `1 > 2 > 3 > 1`, where `a > b` indicates "a wins against b"

There are no other possibilities than these two, since each number must be assigned a "winning" and a "loosing" number out of a pool of two numbers. So we've got exactly two possibilities to order the numbers into winning/loosing conditions.

Now we only need to count the number of times the first player wins choosing one of the above configurations (`w`) and the draws (`d`). The number of games that are won by player is thus `w` using the chosen configuration, or `N - draws - w` if the opposite configuration is chosen.

```
int[] A = readPlayerOne();
int[] B = readPlayerTwo();

int draws = 0;
int wins = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(A[i] == B[i])
        draws++;
    else if(A[i] - 1 == B[i] || A[i] == 1 && B[i] == 3)
        //wins according to the first configuration
        wins++;
}

return max(N - draws - wins, wins);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all we can ignore the lines which have two similar numbers as they yield a draw (not affecting the score) you can make use of the following hints:

- every one of (rock, paper, scissors) have 1 lose, 1 win and 1 draw combinations as example:

  rock can win scissors, lose from paper, and draw with another rock, so if you assume 1-2 makes player1 wins you can tell that 1-3 is a lose
- you can save only the count of each combination of player1 player2 inputs in a 2D array
- you only have 2 combinations as the following:

1-2 win gives:
2-1, 1-3, 3-2 lose
AND 2-3, 1-2, 3-1 win

1-3 win gives:
2-1, 1-3, 3-2 win
AND 2-3, 1-2, 3-1 lose

so you can simply get the maximum of them

```
int in[][] = new int[4][4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        in[i][j] = 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
    int p1 = scan.nextInt();
    int p2 = scan.nextInt();
    if(p1 != p2)
        in[p1][p2]++;
}

int maxWins = Math.max(in[1][2]+in[2][3]+in[3][1], 
                       in[1][3]+in[2][1]+in[3][2]);
```